# jQuery fancybox onClosed strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Can someone look at my script below and tell me why my fancybox is behaving so weird? I have a form that when the fancy box closes it should clear the form data and collapse the div that the results were in.  It works 7/10 times?? how could this happen? and the actual function takes place the second after the fancybox is reopened, not actually on close

I'm stumped

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#login,#login2,#contactBox,#contactBox2').fancybox({
            'overlayColor'      : '#000',
            'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
            'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
            'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
            'easingIn'          : 'easeOutExpo',
            'easingOut'         : 'easeInExpo',
            'speedIn'           : 600, 
            'speedOut'          : 200,
            'onClosed'          : function() {
                        $('#sub_cont').hide(250, function() {
                        $('#IDsearchform input').val('');
                     });
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can someone please help me? I've come this far.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the script you posted and it seems to work for me when I implemented the link (firing a fancybox), a simple input toclear the content and a div to hide. However I had to remove the easing options since they were rising errors in the jquery - could that be a problem?.  if you post the full/minimal code which does not work for you I can have a look. 
K